# GetRenderingDatasourceArgs.DatasourceRoots never use the other items added into it

Tags: datasource

I'm extending `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering`, and from the code there's `GetRenderingDatasourceArgs.DatasourceRoots` and I am adding items on it:

```
var customdatasourceroot = "/sitecore/content//*[@@templateid='{templateid}']";
if (!string.isnullorempty(customdatasourceroot))
{
    var obj = renderingdatasourceargs.contentdatabase.getitem(renderingdatasourceargs.contextitempath);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var objarray = (item[])null;
        objarray = obj.axes.selectitems(customdatasourceroot);

        if (objarray != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in objarray)
            {
                renderingdatasourceargs.DatasourceRoots.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when the dialog box appears, only the nodes for the current datasource appears on the selection box.

What am I missing?

Here is some part of the code:

```
public class AddRendering : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering
{
    protected new static void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        ...
        GetRenderingDatasourceArgs renderingDatasourceArgs = new GetRenderingDatasourceArgs(itemNotNull)
        {
            ContextItemPath = args.Parameters["contextitempath"],
            ContentLanguage = WebEditUtil.GetClientContentLanguage()
        };

        CorePipeline.Run("getRenderingDatasource", (PipelineArgs)renderingDatasourceArgs);
    }
}

....

var customdatasourceroot = "/sitecore/content//*[@@templateid='{templateid}']";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customdatasourceroot))
{
    var obj = renderingDatasourceArgs.ContentDatabase.GetItem(renderingDatasourceArgs.ContextItemPath);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var objarray = (Item[])null;
        objarray = obj.Axes.SelectItems(customdatasourceroot);

        if (objarray != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in objarray)
            {
                renderingDatasourceArgs.DatasourceRoot.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

....

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(renderingDatasourceArgs.CurrentDatasource))
{
    Item obj = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(renderingDatasourceArgs.CurrentDatasource);
    WebEditResponse.Eval(FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.handleMessage('chrome:placeholder:controladded', {{ id: '{0}', openProperties: {1}, dataSource: '{2}' }});", (object)itemNotNull.ID.Guid.ToString("N").ToUpperInvariant(), (object)flag.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), (object)obj.ID.Guid.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant())));
}
```

I want to display certain nodes from the tree so that user can select from different sites.

Comment: What is your requirement here?

Comment: I want to display certain nodes from the tree so that user can select from different sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `var obj = renderingDatasourceArgs.ContentDatabase.GetItem(renderingDatasourceArgs.ContextItemPath)` you get the current context Item (data source).

Then, you call `obj.Axes.SelectItems(customdatasourceroot)` to apply your query.

Your query is good, the issue is that you are applying it on the current data source item `axes`. Axes are a kind of directional query. So basically you are looking for all `[@@templateid='{templateid}']` below your current data source item.

To fix it you need to change the root item to something more high level on the hierarchy.

Comment: HA! yea you're right. *facepalm*